# selenium standalone terminates with unknown error

Tags: protractor

when i start my test the browser opens and an ip is displayed after few sec the ip is changed to "data;" in terminal the test is been looped and sends err ms

empresss-Mac-mini:myApp admin$ protractor test/e2e.js 
    Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
    [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
    Started
    A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
    F

```
Failures:
1) header Module should check title text
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Message:
    Failed: header is not defined
  Stack:
    ReferenceError: header is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/myApp/www/head.spec.js:8:13)
    From: Task: Run it("should check title text") in control flow
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/myApp/www/head.spec.js:7:4)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/myApp/www/head.spec.js:1:63)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 30.019 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

my config file is

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['../www/head.spec.js'],
  multiCapabilities: [
  {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }],
  onPrepare: function(){
        browser.driver.get('http://192.168.1.2:8100');
    }
}
```

i named it as e2e.js
my test file is

```
describe('header Module', function(){

   beforeEach(function() {
        var header = element(by.css('title'));
    });

   it('should check title text',function(){
        expect(header.getText()).toContain('Ionic Blank Starter');    
    });
});
```

i downloaded an blank ionic app and i want to test the header contains elements "Ionic Blank Starter"

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling async code well in your project. `header.getText()` returns a promise which you need to resolve before asserting the text. You can do something like this:

```
describe('header Module', function(){
it('should check title text',function(callback){
    var header = element(by.css('.title'));
    header.getText()
       .then(function (text) {
           expect(text).toContain('Ionic Blank Starter');
           callback();
       }); 
});
});
```

Comment: no change, again the same error is coming in terminal (error displayed above)

Comment: updated my answer, error was because you have defined header in `beforeEach` which local for that method and using that in some other method.

Comment: Failures:
1) header Module should check title text
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.       i started my test a browser opens but it shows blank page i did not opened that app

Comment: Does it open given url?

Comment: in address bar first "data;" after few sec my url then the browser close automatically without opening my app that is that header page is not displayed

Comment: Well, two things I noticed in your code. First: Seems you are using some development codebase which starts your app on localhost. So have you started your server before running test. Second: You are trying to find an element by css `title`, the css locator `title` is not correct. If your intention is to find title of app then you can use `browser.getTitle()`.

Comment: i used this id but still i get the same error <h1 class="title" id="titleId">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>